# small excel macro-enabled file takes 5 minutes to open on a fast computer, why?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, excel-2007

I have an unbelievably slow opening excel 2007 macro-enabled workbook that is only 950kb in file size. It’s got 2 worksheets, one is empty, and the other has about 1,000 records spanning 10 columns. The file also contains 3 short macros, one of them being a web data query. I’m trying to figure out why the file opens so slow (like 5mins). If it's the web data query macro code, I would like to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest way to determine if its the web query, would be to:

```
- cache the web query data
- turn off the web query
- have the code populate from the cached data
- restart the sheet and time it.
```

If it's noticeably faster then you can probably blame the web query.

Comment: the web query does not run on file open.

Comment: @hurricaneditka16 well then how could it be the "web data query macro code" If that code doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a ton of formulas in it? If you do and have them on Auto-Calculate it can cause a myriad of issues with being slow.

Also VBA likes to generate a lot of garbage if you change code a lot. You might try creating a new sheet and copying and pasting everything into the new one and delete the original. It'll start fresh. You won't be able to see the garbage that VBA kept around but it's decently well documented.

There is a free add-on for it somewhere on the web, just Google "VBA Code Cleaner"

Comment: don't have a lot of formulas. formulas are set to manual. 

i will look into your other 2 suggestions.